Mosquitto MQTT broker log message parsing
I need help on parsing the mosquitto mqtt broker log message.
parsing message: 2024-11-15T11:23:03: New connection from 172.17.0.2:41779 on port 1883.
the connection match is : None
the disconnection match is : None
parsed data received is : None
Message parsed failed
log message from topic $SYS/broker/log/N: 2024-11-15T11:23:03: Client <unknown> disconnected, not authorised.
parsing message: 2024-11-15T11:23:03: Client <unknown> disconnected, not authorised.

Here I have already written a code which tries to parse the above log message but when I try to run it I'm  getting the following:
the connection match is : None
the disconnection match is : None
parsed data received is : None

It is not able to read and parse the log message. Can you please help on this?
Thank you

I have already written a code can you show a code, so at least we know what programming language you are using

I have written code in python language. I've written a code which needs to parse the log message received from mqtt client to get the client ip address, port number

clearly your super secret can't show anyone code fails at parse the log message - why? maybe it's line 37, who knows
